How to give FTP access to a directory under /var/www but not other directories
I have a Debian machine with a sudo user called ‘foo’. foo has permissions to /var/www and everything under it, including a directory called /var/www/uat. Here’s what that looks like:
drwxr-s--- 32 foo www-data 4096 Aug 26 21:47 www

I created another user called ‘bar’ and made /var/www/uat/ their home directory (by using the –d option in useradd). I changed the permission for bar to have access to /var/www/uat by doing this:
sudo chown -R bar /var/www/uat/
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/uat/
sudo chmod -R 750 /var/www/uat/
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/uat/

However, user bar is unable to cd to /var/www/uat/ and the login also leaves it in / instead of the home directory (/var/www/uat/), and I believe it is because bar has no access to /var/www. How do I resolve this? I want bar to be able to only use /var/www/uat/ and not see or at least not access other directories under /var/www/. The user bar is basically an ftp user and doesn’t need to have access to anything else.
